# Connecting hbase remotely using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, spark-streaming

I configured Hadoop and spark in my windows (which is my local) and i have cloudera setup in a vm (same machine) which is having hbase inside it.
I am trying to pull data using spark stream and put it into hbase which is in in vm.

is it possible to do this?

my attempt:

package hbase

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory,HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}


object Connect {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
  val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val tablename = "Acadgild_spark_Hbase"

val HbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  HbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","192.168.117.133")
  HbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181")

  val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(HbaseConf);

  val admin = connection.getAdmin();

 val listtables=admin.listTables()

listtables.foreach(println)

  }
}
```

Error:

```
18/08/08 21:05:09 INFO ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.117.133:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$$Lambda$13/1357491107@12d1bfb1
18/08/08 21:05:15 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server 192.168.117.133/192.168.117.133:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18/08/08 21:05:15 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 192.168.117.133/192.168.117.133:2181, initiating session
18/08/08 21:05:15 INFO ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server 192.168.117.133/192.168.117.133:2181, sessionid = 0x16518f57f950012, negotiated timeout = 40000
18/08/08 21:05:16 WARN ConnectionUtils: Can not resolve quickstart.cloudera, please check your network
java.net.UnknownHostException: quickstart.cloudera
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionUtils.getStubKey(ConnectionUtils.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionImplementation.java:1126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionImplementation.java:1148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionImplementation.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getMaster(ConnectionImplementation.java:1202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3055)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:444)
    at azure.iothub$.main(iothub.scala:35)
    at azure.iothub.main(iothub.scala)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show your configurations, your code attempts and any errors you get

Comment: hi i edited my question with my code and error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this error, you cannot use `quickstart.cloudera` in your code because the networking stack is using DNS to try to reach it, but your external router doesn't know about your VM.

---

You need to use `localhost`, then ensure that the VM has correctly been configured to use the ports that you need to connect to.

However, I think Zookeeper is returning that hostname back into your code. Therefore, you must edit the Hosts file on your Host OS machine to add a line item.

For example

```
127.0.0.1 localhost quickstart.cloudera
```

Or, you can go poke around in the `zookeeper-shell` or Cloudera Manager (in the HBase configurations) and edit `quickstart.cloudera` to return the address `192.168.117.133` instead